# WPF exe running very slow compared to running in Visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I have created an application in WPF using the MVVM pattern.

The application is running fine in the Visual Studio debugger, but when I'm running the exe from the debug/release folder, it becomes very slow.

Here is my `RelayCommand` class:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        bool res = false;
        if (canExecute != null)
        {
            res = canExecute(parameter);
        }

        return res;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }

    private static bool DefaultCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I remove the **`CanExcecute()`** method from my `RelayCommand` class, then the exe version runs as normal.

Please can anyone explain why this thing is happening? Is it for the `CanExecuteChanged` event handler?

Comment: Hard to say, we don't know what kind of logic you're running in CanExecute. Create a [MCVE]

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am checking some property from database, I think that fetching is the issue. If i just return true from that CanExcecute Method, the exe is working fine.

Comment: If I just iterate throw collection without fetching db it's working fine :)

Comment: The database access is obviously slow for some reason.  Why?  Could be a thousand things.  You should be monitoring the query to the database (e.g.,Sql Server Profiler if you're using sql server), then examine why it's taking so long.  The answer about `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` is also correct, it sucks. Lastly, that entire CanExecute method can be replaced with `return canExecute?.Invoke(parameter);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Don't use the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event.

The current implementation of the `CommandManager` enqueues a requery of all commands as a `Dispatcher` action with a `DispatcherPriority.Background`. That means, whenever your application is idle, the `CommandManager` will call the `CanExecute()` methods of all commands you have registered in the `CommandManager`. If any of this methods does consume some resources (like using a Database or reading a File), then you will probably notice the overall performance drop of your application.

E.g. Prism has its own implementation of the `ICommand` without subscribing to the `CommandManager`'s event. This works great too, but you have to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` methods explicitly when you want to update the command state. This is normally not a problem, since you should be interested only in a few of commands at one time, not in all the commands in your application.

2. Don't use any heavy-weight tasks in your `CanExecute()` methods.

They should be like this, short and fast:

```
public bool CanExecute()
{
    return this.isIdle && this.someFlag && !this.CommandAbort.CanExecute();
}
```